# C# linq pivot or crosstab or transpose?

Tags: c#, linq

First post ever so please forgive if I am out of line.

```
StreamWriter noteswriter = new StreamWriter(directoryPath + "\\" + "Notes.CSV");

var NotesQuery =
    from w in
        (from line in BillSummaryQuery1
         let linerecord2 = line.Split(',').ToList()
         where linerecord2[0] == "RB" && linerecord2[1] == "MICA" && linerecord2[6].Trim() == "1" && linerecord2[7].Trim() == "H" && linerecord2[9].Trim() == "D" && Regex.IsMatch(linerecord2[10].Substring(4, 1), @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") && linerecord2[10].Substring(2, 1) == " "
         select string.Concat(linerecord2[2], ",", linerecord2[3], ",", linerecord2[10].Trim())
         )
    let lineorder3 = w.Split(',').ToList()
    select new
    {
        colA = lineorder3[0],
        colB = lineorder3[1],
        colC = lineorder3[2]
    };

var NotesQuery1 =
from w in NotesQuery
    group w by new { w.colA, w.colB, w.colC } into g
    select new
    {
        colA = g.Key.colA, 
        colB = g.Key.colB, 
        colC = g.Key.colC
    };

foreach (var item in NotesQuery1)
{
    noteswriter.WriteLine(item);
    toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.PerformStep();
}

noteswriter.Dispose();
noteswriter.Close();
```

This gives me an output such as:

```
{colA = AccountA,colB = Number1,colC = AccountA }

{colA = AccountA,colB = Number1,colC = AccountHolderA }

{colA = AccountA,colB = Number1,colC = Address1 }

{colA = AccountA,colB = Number1,colC = Address2 }

{colA = AccountB,colB = Number2,colC = AccountA }

{colA = AccountB,colB = Number2,colC = AccountHolderB }

{colA = AccountB,colB = Number2,colC = Address1 }
```

I don't know how to get the CSV file to be written as:

```
AccountA,Number1,AccountA,AccountHolderA,Address1,Address2

AccountB,Number2,AccountA,AccountHolderB,Address
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If `colA = AccountA,colB = Number1` appears further down the list would that extend the first line out past `Address2` or would it start a new line?

Comment: [link](http://i53.tinypic.com/qz3odd.png) is that I'm looking for. It would just extend the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var NotesQuery =
    from line in BillSummaryQuery1
    let linerecord2 = line.Split(',')
    where linerecord2[0] == "RB"
    where linerecord2[1] == "MICA"
    where linerecord2[6].Trim() == "1"
    where linerecord2[7].Trim() == "H"
    where linerecord2[9].Trim() == "D"
    where Regex.IsMatch(linerecord2[10].Substring(4, 1), @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
    where linerecord2[10].Substring(2, 1) == " "
    group linerecord2[10].Trim() by new
    {
        A = linerecord2[2],
        B = linerecord2[3],
    } into g
    select String.Join(",", (new []
    {
        g.Key.A,
        g.Key.B,
    }).Concat(g.Distinct()).ToArray());

foreach (var item in NotesQuery)
{
    noteswriter.WriteLine(item);
    toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.PerformStep();
}
```

---

EDIT: Here's how to make the number of columns equal.

```
var NotesQuery =
    (from line in BillSummaryQuery1
    let linerecord2 = line.Split(',')
    where linerecord2[0] == "RB"
    where linerecord2[1] == "MICA"
    where linerecord2[6].Trim() == "1"
    where linerecord2[7].Trim() == "H"
    where linerecord2[9].Trim() == "D"
    where Regex.IsMatch(linerecord2[10].Substring(4, 1), @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
    where linerecord2[10].Substring(2, 1) == " "
    group linerecord2[10].Trim() by new
    {
        A = linerecord2[2],
        B = linerecord2[3],
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.A,
        g.Key.B,
        Cs = g.Distinct().ToArray()
    }).ToArray();

var max = NotesQuery.Max(nq => nq.Cs.Length);

var padding = from n in Enumerable.Range(0, max) select "";

var NotesQuery2 =
    from nq in NotesQuery
    select String.Join(",", (new []
    {
        nq.A,
        nq.B,
    }).Concat(nq.Cs).Concat(padding).Take(max + 2).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate it. It worked! I am learning C# and LINQ. Any helpful tips, suggestions or resources you recommend?

Comment: @SaidurRahman - I'd get "LINQPad" if you don't already use it. It's awesome for testing LINQ code. It's worth paying for autocomplete. Also, you should upvote and accept my answer. ;-)

Comment: It says Vote Up requires 15 reputation. I have only one. Thanks I will follow you! This was my first question and really glad I am here.

Comment: @SaidurRahman - No worries. Welcome aboard. It won't take you long to get reputation. Just start answering questions.

Comment: Thanks for everything. Just one question, when I write it as a CSV, ClientA has 1 more line than ClientB, hence, it has an extra comma in a line for ClientA but drops out for ClientB. Anyway to fix this? as in the picture above it should say (missing) or leave it empty rather than dropping it out

Comment: Thanks again! But the problem is that the edited version is reducing the number of columns rather than going up? I want to increase the "," in the CSV.

Comment: @SaidurRahman - Simple mistake `.Take(max)` should have been `.Take(max + 2)`. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)